# sbd asking for cache data failed

Tags: installation, boot

**BACKGROUND:** I have been trying live USB versions of Ubuntu on my "Dell inspiron mini" for several years. None of the previous versions were able to detect the high resolution screen (1366x768). Finally version 12.04 was able to detect the screen properly so i went ahead with the installation. I am relatively new to linux so I accepted all the defaults during installation (dual boot with Windows XP) and it seemed to go well.

**Problem:** After rebooting and choosing "Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-31-generic-pea" from the GNU GRUB boot menu i get the following and ubuntu will not continue booting:

```
* Stopping save kernel messages         [ OK ]
* Checking battery state...             [ OK ]
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibilty   [ OK ]
53.796074] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] asking for cache data failed
```

**Attempts to fix:** I have tried booting into the "recovery mode" and choosing "repair broken packages" as well as "check all file systems", but no change to the main problem. I tried "run in failsafe graphic mode" - but this failed ("Fatal server error: no screens found".)
I also tried doing a complete reinstallation from the liveUSB - but no change in the result.

**Computer specifications:** Dell Inspiron Mini 10, Intel Atom CPU Z530 1.32ghz, Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 500, 160 GB hard disk drive (currently 118 GB allocated to Windows and the remaining used by the failed Ubuntu installation.)

**Question:** Why does it say [sdb] instead of [sda] in the error above? I thought that/sdb refers to a second physical hard drive - but there is only one hard drive in this computer. Or is the problem something completely different? What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you install grub on installation flash drive. Than you remove it so OS can't boot? Insert pen back into PC, reboot. If success do `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. Then try to reboot without flash pen. Or do something else about flash drive.

Comment: Martini - I think your answer is correct (I'm testing that now) - but if that is the case, why did this happen when I choose the default options?

Answer (score 0):

it will be a card-reader that is sdb, and it has no cache so the system rerurns this message